# Whats the default application location for PHP apps deployed with EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a php(Centos) application that I am trying to deploy with Amazon Beanstalk.

My appplication is in /srv/sites/myapp.

So I setup my application and environment and uplaoded a zip file(myapp.zip) of my site.

I can see that the instances are created but the site does'nt work becuase my application is not uploaded to /srv/sites/myapp.

I am trying to figure out where EBS unzips my application and puts the files on my server.

Can someone please tell me if there is a default location where EBS could possible put the application files?

I checked /var/www.....

Comment: On AWS, EBS stands for Elastic Block Store, not Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

The default location is /var/www/html, and it uses Amazon Linux (which is RPM-based)

Answer (score 0):

It resides inside `/usr/share/nginx/html/` in case of php with nginx